# delay addclass - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delay the `addclass` function in this plugin however it's not working. I have added `.delay(14000)` just before the `.addClass` function.

Code:

```
if (typeof a.cookieguard.displayMessage === "undefined") {
    a.cookieguard.displayMessage = function (b, c) {
        a("body").delay(14000)
                 .addClass("cookie-guard")
                 .attr("marginTop", a("body").css("marginTop"))
                 .css("margin", 0)
                 .delay(b).animate({
                      marginTop: a(".cookie-guard-msg").outerHeight()
                  }, a.cookieguard.settings.slideSpeed);

        a(".cookie-guard-msg").css("top", -a(".cookie-guard-msg").outerHeight());

        a(".cookie-guard-msg").delay(b)
                              .show()
                              .animate({top: 0}, a.cookieguard.settings.slideSpeed);

        if (a.cookieguard.settings.messageHideDelay != null) {
            a.cookieguard.settings.messageHideTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                a.cookieguard.hideMessage(0)
            }, c)
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.delay()` only works on calls that use the jQuery effects queue (Like the common animations).

To do what you need here, I'd use a regular JavaScript `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() { a("body").addClass("cookie-guard"); /* etc. */ }, 14000);
```

Comment: Woo, glad it's sorted! :)